# Django different admins one panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

First, sorry for my poor english.

I'm trying to make a Django system that supports different admins to get the same admin panel, but showing them different objects, that belong to the same CustomModel.

Example:

First step: --> Login
Seconds step: --> Redirect to admin panel (django.contrib.admin.site)

and.. nothing else.

The problem is that I don't know how to show in that panel the objects that corresponds to the logged admin.

Thanks! Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where [Django Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) enter the picture

> Django comes with a simple permissions system. It provides a way to
>   assign permissions to specific users and groups of users.
>
> It’s used by the Django admin site, but you’re welcome to use it in
>   your own code.
>
> The Django admin site uses permissions as follows:
>
> Access to view the “add” form and add an object is limited to users
>   with the “add” permission for that type of object. Access to view the
>   change list, view the “change” form and change an object is limited to
>   users with the “change” permission for that type of object. Access to
>   delete an object is limited to users with the “delete” permission for
>   that type of object.

If you give a staff user permissions to work with only a certain type of object, that's all that he will see in the admin area.

If you have lots of different admin, you can put them into groups and grant permissions for the groups.

Comment: Te amooooooooo! Mil gracias! Incredibly grateful.

Comment: Glad to have been of help